# Incorporating regular expression symbols to check if string in regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a program that determines whether specific strings are in the language of a regular expression specified in the text file. In the regular expression there are special symbols that are substituted since they aren't traditional keyboard characters. Those substitutions are: e for epsilon, N for the empty set, U for union, o for concatenation and * for the star operator. I'm having trouble trying to figure out if I need to write code to explain this substitution so that the program runs correctly for example strings longer than one character. For example checking if the regular expression contains U and then define what that means, etc.

An example text file looks like:

```
12
(((1U(2o1))U(2o2))o((1U2)*))
1
21
22
1212121
21121212
22121212
e
2
```

My program so far:

```
'''
Searching text for string that are in the language
of a regular expression
'''
import sys
import re



# Part 1
# Read from file (alphabet, regular expression, sequence of strings)

fileName = sys.argv[1] # open file
# outPut = sys.argv[2]
alphabet = []
inputs = []
strings = {}

# Read lines from text file and store alphabet and regX
f = open(fileName, 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
alphabet = lines[0].strip()
del lines[0]
regx = lines[0]
del lines[0]


print(alphabet, regx, sep='\n') # debug print statement

# Remaining lines are the test regular expressions
# print(lines) # debug print statement

for line in lines:
    splitLine = line.split()
    strings[splitLine[0]] = ",".join(splitLine[0:])

print('Printing out the strings:', strings) # debug print statement

# Substitute for epsilon, concat, empty set, union and star



# Testing if the strings are apart of the regular expressions
for string in strings:
    if string not in regx:
        print('False', string)
    else:
        print('True', string)
```

In an example output of that particular text file is:

```
12
(((1U(2o1))U(2o2))o((1U2)*))

Printing out the strings: {'1212121': '1212121', 'e': 'e', '22': '22'...}

False 1212121
False e
False 22
False 22121212
True 2
False 21
True 1
False 21121212
```

The correct output should be:

```
True 1
True 21
True 22
True 1212121
True 21121212
True 22121212
False e
False 2
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by a string being "in" a regular expression. Are you trying to tell whether a string is in the *language specified by* a regular expression, or are you trying to determine whether the string is in *the text of* the regular expression? Is `aaa` in `a*`, or is `*` in `a*`?

Comment: @user2357112 Yes sorry whether the string is in the language specified by the regular expression within the text file. Is aaa in a* not is * in a*

Comment: `in` isn't going to cut it. You're going to want to either write your own regular expression parser, NFA-based or DFA-based, or cop out and rewrite your regexes and inputs in the format expected by the built-in `re` module so you can fob all the work onto that module. Guessing from the input format, you're probably supposed to write your own parser.

Comment: Doesn't translating your "regex" in your example to regex yield: (((1|(21))|(22))((1|2)*))  And couldn't you programmaticly perform the necessary substitutions to do that translation, and then use re.match?

Comment: @user2357112 regular expression parser meaning convert the RE to an NFA and then test the strings on the NFA?

Comment: @BrxttB: Pretty much.

Comment: @tekim The program is just reading in text files so I'm not going to see what regular expression I'm going to get beforehand so it has to be something that can handle a variety of test cases/regular expressions. Unless I can somehow convert the symbols to the ones re uses then I may have to just convert it to an NFA then go from there

Comment: @BrxttB It should be a pretty simple substitution: "o" in your regex can just be deleted as in standard regular expressions, just putting two things next to each other does a concatenation. "U" becomes "|", "e" can be replaced by /x + hex code for epsilon. I am not sure how "N" would translate to a standard regular expression, and in your "regex" how does one escape these special characters.  i.e. what if I really do want to match a "U"?

Comment: Correction on my earlier comment, should be \x not /x

Comment: @tekim I'm not sure how to replace the symbols. I realize I do have to convert the RE into an NFA, but I'm not sure how to go about that. I've read the algorithm, but I'm having a tough time converting it and if I should use a stack or not.

Comment: @BrxttB regx.replace("|", "U")

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on tekim's suggestions:

> "o" in your regex can just be deleted as in standard regular
>   expressions, just putting two things next to each other does a
>   concatenation. "U" becomes "|"

- Drop the `strings` dictionary; it serves no purpose but to mix up the order of the strings.
- To translate your kind of *regular expression* into the standard syntax:

  ```
  regx = regx.strip().replace("U", "|").replace("o", "")+"$"
  ```
- To check the example strings and produce the correct output:

  ```
  for line in lines:
      string = line.strip()
      if re.match(regx, string):
          print('True', string)
      else:
          print('False', string)
  ```